# how to use pip to install pkg from requirement file without reinstall

Tags: docker, pip

I am trying to build an Docker image. My *Dockerfile* is like this:

```
FROM python:2.7
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8300"]
```

And my *requirement.txt* file like this:

```
wheel==0.29.0
numpy==1.11.3
django==1.10.5
django-cors-headers==2.0.2
gspread==0.6.2
oauth2client==4.0.0
```

Now, I have a little change in my code, and i need *pandas*, so i add it in to requirement.txt file

```
wheel==0.29.0
numpy==1.11.3
pandas==0.19.2
django==1.10.5
django-cors-headers==2.0.2
gspread==0.6.2
oauth2client==4.0.0
```

`pip install -r requirement.txt` will install all packages in that file, although almost of them has installed before. My question is how to make pip install *pandas* only? That will save the time to build image.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -U -r requirement.txt`?

Comment: Yes, i've already tried. But, it's not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rebuild your image after changing *requirement.txt* with `docker build -t <your_image> .`, I guess it cann't be done because each time when docker runs `docker build`, it'll start an intermediate container from base image, and it's a new environment so `pip` obviously will need to install all of dependencies.

You can consider to build your own base image on `python:2.7` with common dependencies pre-installed, then build your application image on your own base image. Once there's a need to add more dependencies, manually re-build the base image on the previous one with only extra dependencies installed, and then maybe optionally `docker push` it back to your registry.

Hope this could be helpful :-)