# Docker and pip install: avoid installing all packages when some are already installed

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to build the stack of a Python project. This is a `dockerfile` snippet that handles the requirements.

```
# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/production.txt \
    && rm -rf /requirements
```

With that configuration I'm able to cache the requirements but when I modify `production.txt` (e.g. updating even a single package) Docker reinstalls everything all over again.

I know Docker needs to create a fresh container but is there a way to avoid reinstalling everything again but installing only what Is necessary?

Comment: Why not have the base image of the most common packages that do not need constant updates/install then specify only the that do require updates/reinstalls in requirements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use pip to install pkg from requirement file without reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017522/how-to-use-pip-to-install-pkg-from-requirement-file-without-reinstall)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, no, there is not a way to avoid reinstalling everything in `production.txt`.

From [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache), in the `Leverage build cache` section:

> For the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the file(s) in the
>   image are examined and a checksum is calculated for each file. The
>   last-modified and last-accessed times of the file(s) are not
>   considered in these checksums. During the cache lookup, the checksum
>   is compared against the checksum in the existing images. If anything
>   has changed in the file(s), such as the contents and metadata, then
>   the cache is invalidated

Since you have changed `production.txt`, the cache is invalidated and docker starts from the previously valid layer and installs everything.

Now, if you have multiple `requirements.txt` files, you may be able to leverage some caching by doing separate steps of copy & install:

```
COPY requirements1.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements1.txt

COPY requirements2.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements2.txt
```

This could have other downsides, but it may allow you to partially reduce reinstall times by putting long-living packages that aren't likely to update in `requirements1.txt` and less stable ones in `requirements2.txt`. Changing `requirements2.txt` then would only cause those requirements to be reinstalled.

However, as a warning, this would also mean that changing `requirements1.txt` would fully require a re-install of `requirements2.txt` as it comes after the `requirements1.txt` steps. This isn't different than the original behavior of one file, but do know that the order matters here. There are a few other downsides to this flow as well, but they get fairly pedantic.